# Mongo Db $not $in query with multiple keys

Tags: mongodb

I have a Mongo db collection of documents which contains _id , id1, id2, where (id1, id2) are unique together.
I want to find all the documents except a list of dictionaries of (id1, id2).

In other words, I want all the documents except the except_arr.

Example of the documents:

```
{ _id: 1, id1: 25, id2: 1030 },
{ _id: 2, id1: 25, id2: 1031 },
{ _id: 3, id1: 1024, id2: 2048 },
{ _id: 4, id1: 1552, id2: 1284 }
```

Example of the array to except:

```
except_arr = [
    {id1: 1024, id2: 2048},
    {id1: 1552, id: 1284}
]
```

The result should be:

```
{ _id: 1, id1: 25, id2: 1030 },
{ _id: 2, id1: 25, id2: 1031 }
```

Comment: Can you update your question with an example document?

Comment: I update my example. Thank you for your response!

Comment: try this script: 

db.getCollection('test').find({id1: { $nin: [1024, 1552] }, id2: { $nin: [2048, 2048] } })

Comment: @GlennMateus this solution won't work because (id1, id2) are unique together. 

The idea is to find something like 
$nin : {"$or": [
            {'id1': 1024, 'id2': 2048},
            {'id1': 1552, 'id2': 1284}
        ]
}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're looking for is called [$nor](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/nor/)

```
db.collection.find({
  $nor: [
    {
      id1: 1024,
      id2: 2048
    },
    {
      id1: 1552,
      id2: 1284
    }
  ]
})
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Nw6GeJg91sg)

Answer (score 0):

After reviewing the code I've commented and see what Mohamad said I got this solution:

```js
db.getCollection('test').find({
    $or: [ 
        { id1: { $nin: [1024, 1552] } }, 
        { id2: { $nin: [2048, 1284] } }  
    ]
})
```

My database objects:

```js
[
    { _id: 1, id1: 25, id2: 1030 },
    { _id: 2, id1: 25, id2: 1031 },
    { _id: 3, id1: 1024, id2: 2048 },
    { _id: 4, id1: 1552, id2: 1284 },

    { _id: 5, id1: 1024, id2: 3 },
    { _id: 6, id1: 4, id2: 1284 }
]
```

The result:

```js
[
    { _id: 1, id1: 25, id2: 1030 },
    { _id: 2, id1: 25, id2: 1031 },
    { _id: 5, id1: 1024, id2: 3 },
    { _id: 6, id1: 4, id2: 1284 }
]
```

**EDIT** 
Below a example with different id1 and id2 
*Online playground to test: https://mongoplayground.net/p/2vQyTkpgHNI 
My collection:
[image: Collection]

The query result.
[image: Query result]

Comment: Thank you Glenn for your response. However, it won't work to find the result excepting a list of dictionaries.

For example, if the except array is :

except_arr = [
    {id1: 4, id: 1284},
    {id1: 25, id2: 1030}
]


db.getCollection('test').find({
    $or: [ 
        { id1: { $nin: [4, 25] } }, 
        { id2: { $nin: [1284, 1030] } }  
    ]
})

You will get:
[
    { _id: 3, id1: 1024, id2: 2048 },
    { _id: 5, id1: 1024, id2: 3 },
]

When the expected results should contains the documents with ids in (2,3,5,6)

Comment: Thank you Glenn for your update. let's change the except_array to:
except_array = [
   {id1:25, id2:1048},
   {id1: 1024, id2: 1030}
] 
In this case, you'll get the documents with ids in (2,4,5,6) in the results. 
However, in this case the expected output should be all the result (because of the Unique Together key). Have a look to the following link:
https://mongoplayground.net/p/O8ukP4FZEs0